# count occurence of rows with specific status without using subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Here is my table

**loan_id** **bid_id** **lender_id** **borrower_id** **amount** **interest** **duration** **loan_status**

```
1   1  60  63  300.00  12.00  3  'completed'
2   2  61  63  300.00  12.00  3  'completed'
3   3  62  63  300.00  12.00  3  'pending',
4   1  62  63  300.00  12.00  3  'pending'
7   4  60  63  300.00  12.00  3  'completed'
```

I want to pull only those bid_id whose loan_status of all records is **completed**. It means if there is any record of **bid_id** with status **pending** then it will not pull that record.

I am using the followin query that is working fine:

```
SELECT bid_id 
FROM loan 
WHERE bid_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT l.bid_id 
    FROM loan l 
    WHERE l.`loan_status` = 'pending' 
    AND l.bid_id = bid_id 
    GROUP BY l.`bid_id` 
    HAVING COUNT(l.`bid_id`)>= 1 
) 
GROUP BY bid_id
```

Is there any other way in which we can get desired result without using sub query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select bid_id
from loan
group by bid_id
having sum(loand_status = 'pending') = 0
```